# Redefinition of a class C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a clock program and having some issue with the Clock external class and it gives me the error "redefinition of Clock::Clock()" in Clock.cpp file

**Clock.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Counter.h"
#include "Clock.h"

using namespace std;

Clock::Clock()
{
}

void Clock::Tick() {
    _seconds.Increment();
    if (_seconds.Value() == 60)
    {
        _seconds.Reset();
        _minutes.Increment();
        if (_minutes.Value() == 60)
        {
            _minutes.Reset();
            _hours.Increment();
            if (_hours.Value() == 24)
                _hours.Reset();
        }
    }
}

void Clock::Reset()
{
    _hours.Reset();
    _minutes.Reset();
    _seconds.Reset();
}

void Clock::PrintTime()
{
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << _hours.Value() << ":";
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << _minutes.Value() << ":";
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << _seconds.Value();
}
```

**Clock.h**

```
#ifndef CLOCK_H
#define CLOCK_H

class Clock
{
    private:
        Counter _hours;
        Counter _minutes;
        Counter _seconds;

    public:
        Clock(): _hours("hours"), _minutes("minutes"), _seconds("seconds"){};
        void Tick();
        void Reset();
        void PrintTime();
};

#endif // CLOCK_H
```

The header guard is included but the compiler keeps giving the error :/
Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've already defined `Clock::Clock()` with the following in the .h `Clock(): _hours("hours"), _minutes("minutes"), _seconds("seconds"){};`

Comment: Thanks, so if I don't have an initializer list do I have to defined the constructor in cpp file? Because some of the instructions I've read they do have..

Comment: You can declare and implement your classes and functions wherever you want, but as a rule of thumb: keep your declarations in the header file and your implementation in the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Craig Young points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125856/redefinition-of-a-class-c#comment75270478_44125856), you've already *implemented* your Clock constructor.

```
Clock(): _hours("hours"), _minutes("minutes"), _seconds("seconds"){};
```

Simply change your header file so that so it only declares the constructor:

```
Clock();
```

And implement it in the source file:

```
Clock::Clock(): _hours("hours"), _minutes("minutes"), _seconds("seconds")
{
}
```

Keep your declarations in your header file, and implementations in your source file.